# If form validation fails

Tags: forms, codeigniter

I want to redirect people to a certain page if the form validations fails. However, I can’t quite figure out how.

If i redirect people at the REDIRECT HERE comment below, it also redirects when it loads up the form and causes a endless loop.

```
public function create() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_adress', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email_adress]');

    if ($this->form_validation->run() !== FALSE) {
        // PASSED
    } 

    else {
        // REDIRECT HERE
    }

    $this->load->view('user_register_view');
}
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Hi @PatrickReck, if any of below answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) or adding your own solution. So, that it indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

You would redirect like so:

```
redirect('insert_URI_here');
```

Or if you are passing it to another method in the same controller you could just do :

```
$this->method_name();
```

However, if you just drop that in your else statement, user_register_view will not load because $this->form_validation->run() will return false either on validation error or non submission of the form.

What you will have to do is add another check to look for validation errors. If validation has failed and there are no validation errors, then your form hasn't been submitted.

So you could do something like this:

```
public function create() {

    $this->form_validation->set_rules('email_adress', 'E-mail', 'required|valid_email|is_unique[users.email_adress]');
    if(($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE) && ($this->form_validation->error_string() == ''));
        //form not submitted yet
        $this->load->view('user_register_view');
    else if ($this->form_validation->run()) {
        // PASSED
    } else {
        //Validation errors
        redirect('insert_URI_here');
    }
}
```

You will have to play around with it. I think $this->form_validation->error_string() should return an empty string if not submitted, but it might be a null value or a false (sorry can't remember off the top of my head).

Comment: Thank you for taking your time to answer my question.
I've tried the code you posted, but I get the following error:

**Fatal error: Call to undefined method CI_Form_validation::validation_errors()**

Comment: Sorry, my bad, I think I had the wrong method. I have corrected my answer. Please try again and let me know if thats it. If not I'll go put together a quick test

Comment: You dont redirect because you want the form values to stay intact(session). you would simply show the form again $this->create_form() mehod

Comment: I agree, I can't see why you would want to do this but I assume he has his reasons